# How to extract child node value from XML as string

Tags: xml, delphi, xpath, xml-parsing

I am trying to loop through some XML and set the value of a string to be equal to a particular nodes contents. The XML looks like:

```
<RootNode>
    <SubNode>test<SubNode>
    <SubNode><ExtraMarkup>some value</ExtraMarkup><SubNode>
</RootNode>
```

Where each sub node can either contain a value or additional XML child nodes. For the first subnode this code works correctly:

```
for Node := 0 to RootNode.childNodes.length-1 do begin
    AttrValue := RootNode.childNodes[Node].selectSingleNode('SubNode').Text; 
    // More code here...
end;
```

The problem is when the subnode contains child nodes. I would like the value of AttrValue to be '`test`' or '`<ExtraMarkup>some value</ExtraMarkup>`' as a string.

If instead of text I get the XML attribute the markup is not preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for Node := 0 to RootNode.childNodes.length-1 do begin

// Check if the Value stored in SubNode node is xml
    if (RootNode.childNodes[Node].selectSingleNode('SubNode').hasChildNodes and
        DealAttributesNode.childNodes[Node].selectSingleNode('SubNode').childNodes[0].hasChildNodes) then begin
        AttrValue := RootNode.childNodes[Node].selectSingleNode('SubNode').childNodes[0].Xml;
    end
    else begin
        AttrValue := RootNode.childNodes[Node].selectSingleNode('SubNode').Text;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably want "IXmlNode.NodeValue".

Here's an example:

```
Function   TGlobalConfig.GetXmlItem(CurNode : IXMLNODE; Section : String; var Value : String; Default : String) : Boolean;
var
  ChildNode: IXMLNode;
begin
  if Assigned(CurNode) then
  begin
    ChildNode := CurNode.ChildNodes.FindNode(Section);
    if (ChildNode <> nil) then
       if   VarIsNull(ChildNode.NodeValue) then 
         Value := Default
       else Value := ChildNode.NodeValue;
       ...
```

Comment: Reading the NodeValue raises an exception if the node's content is not text, such as when child nodes are present.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.Text` you need a property such as `InnerText` or `InnerXml`.